Exploding Gradient (NaN Training Loss And Validation Loss) In Multi Head Self Attention - Vision Transformer
This multihead self attention code causes the training loss and validation loss to become NaN, but when I remove this part, everything goes back to normal. I know that when the training loss and validation loss become NaN, it means there's an exploding gradient there. However, I don’t know what's wrong with my code that's causing the gradient to explode. When I compare it with the official PyTorch code, it looks similar. When I use nn.MultiheadSelfAttention, the gradient doesn’t explode, but when I use my own code, the gradient starts exploding. There is no error message displayed. Does anyone know what's wrong with my code below?
class MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, in_dim, num_heads=8, dropout=0):
    super().__init__()
    self.num_heads = num_heads
    self.head_dim = in_dim // num_heads
    self.conv_q = nn.Conv2d(in_dim, in_dim, kernel_size=1)
    self.conv_k = nn.Conv2d(in_dim, in_dim, kernel_size=1)
    self.conv_v = nn.Conv2d(in_dim, in_dim, kernel_size=1)
    self.att_drop = nn.Dropout(dropout)
    self.proj = nn.Conv2d(in_dim, in_dim, kernel_size=1)
    self.proj_drop = nn.Dropout(dropout)

  def forward(self, x):

    b, _, h, w = x.shape
    
    q = self.conv_q(x)
    k = self.conv_k(x)
    v = self.conv_v(x)

    q = rearrange(q, "b (nh hd) h w -> b nh (h w) hd", nh=self.num_heads)
    k = rearrange(k, "b (nh hd) h w -> b nh (h w) hd", nh=self.num_heads)
    v = rearrange(v, "b (nh hd) h w -> b nh (h w) hd", nh=self.num_heads)

    att_score = q @ k.transpose(2, 3) ** (self.head_dim ** -0.5)
    att_score = F.softmax(att_score, dim=-1)
    att_score = self.att_drop(att_score)

    x = att_score @ v

    x = rearrange(x, 'b nh (h w) hd -> b (nh hd) h w', h=h, w=w)

    x = self.proj(x)
    x = self.proj_drop(x)

    return x


Changing the scaling to use / (math.sqrt(self.head_dim)) solves this issue. I'm not sure why that happens, because self.head_dim ** -0.5 should be equivalent to / (math.sqrt(self.head_dim)). Maybe someone else can explain?

The fix is changing ** to /. In your code, you have q @ k.transpose(2, 3) ** (self.head_dim ** -0.5) - an extra * after the transpose operation. You are exponentiating q @ k.transpose(2, 3) to the power of (self.head_dim ** -0.5) rather than dividing

Ah, I just digested it, thank you for explaining it. Now I can go back to the previous method without using additional libraries
